# HibernateUtil is working on GlassFish but not with Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

When I run my Java web app using Hibernate in NetBeans with GlassFish it works great, but when I run the same Java web app to a Tomcat server I start to receive the message:

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class MyPackage.HibernateUtil"

Any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the following libraries are needed for Tomcat, but not for GlassFish:

slfj4-api

slfj4-simple

Persistance JPA2.0